# Why is my width at 100%?

Tags: html, css

http://geodit.com:8000/d/4

If you go this site, you'll see that $("#coreimage") is set to width:auto.

However, for some reason, it doesn't maintain the width of the cheerios box (Instead, it's 100%...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`coreimage` is a `div`, which is a block element. Block elements, by default, take the full available width, unless you explicitly set the width (to a value other than `auto`), or `float` the element.

I'm not sure what you want the end result to be, but you can either change the element to an inline element (i.e. `span`) or specify `float: left` on your element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you're going for.  You want #coreimage to be the width of its containing image?  That's not how [block level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) work.  A div (or any block level element) will automatically expand to fit its parent unless you specify a width, whereas an inline element (ie span) only takes up the space it needs (ie. you can't specify a width on an inline element, it expands to its children)