# How can I horizontally center a div with unknown length and use min-width?

Tags: html, css

I’m updating some legacy code on an old website, and the CSS is a nightmare.  All I want to do is make the div that holds a username expand a bit when needed, and keep the outer div centered (horizontally) on the page.  The myLabel control is populated based on a user’s name (it typically isn’t pre-defined as John Doe).

Currently, between the 800px value on myContainer, and the 350px value on myGridB, longer usernames are wrapping inside of the div.  I’d rather display the long names on one line and, when possible, not bump the other controls to the next line.

I’ve tried using min-width on myContainer and myGridB , but that just allows the divs to expand across the whole page.  I see this is common behavior for divs in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567900/why-is-my-width-at-100).

I also tried some of the methods in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198153/why-does-the-css-min-width-attribute-not-force-a-div-to-have-the-specified-minim), but that pushed my header content to the left, and I need it centered.

I realize this code is a garbled mess, but I appreciate any ideas…

aspx:

```
<div class="myLogo1">
    <div class="myContainer" style="width: 800px">
        <div class="myGridC myLogo2 first">
            <a onclick="loadMyHomePage(); "><img src="myImageAddress" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="myGridB first last">
            <div class="myHome myGridB first last">
                <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="myHome" ID="myLabel">
                    John Doe
                </asp:Label>
                <span class="myHome">
                    <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="mySettingsPage.aspx" runat="server">
                        My Settings
                    </asp:HyperLink>
                </span>
                <a href="myLogoutPage.aspx") %>">
                    <img src="myLogout.jpg") %>" alt="Logout" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="myGridB first last">
                <div class="myGridA myPaddingA myHome">
                    <a href="myOtherPage" target="_blank">
                        <img width="180px" height="72px" src="myOther.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.myLogo1
{
    background-color: #363636; /* #000000; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
}
.myContainer
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}
.myGridA, .myGridB, .myGridC {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.myGridA
{
    width: 190px;
}
.myGridB
{
    width: 350px;
}
.myGridC
{
    width: 390px;
}
.myLogo2
{
    border: none 0px transparent;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.first
{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.last
{
    margin-right: 0;
}
.myHome
{
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 9pt;
}

.myHome span
{
    font-size: 9pt;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 5px 0px 0px;
}
.myContainer .myPaddingA
{
    padding-left: 44px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's ideas, how I usually horizontally center my divs is I set the container to a certain % width. then i use margin: auto; hope that helped.